# NSString drawing vs. String as NSBezierPath drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbezierpath

I need to perform efficient hit testing against a (potentially huge) number of components so I've represented all my primitives as `NSBezierPath` instances. All working great so far.

Now I'm having trouble converting `NSString` objects, in particular reflecting their position in the view:
I'm using the `NSString (BezierConversions)` category from Apple's SpeedometerView example to convert strings into bezier paths.

The bezier path created for strings looks great but positioning it to match the position of the `NSString` instances location in the view doesn't quite work so I suppose this question is really about

- `NSBezierPath` and `transformUsingAffineTransform:` vs.
- a combination of `NSAffineTransform` applied to a view and `NSString drawAtPoint:`

In my test project even the trivial case fails:

[image: Purple = NSString drawAtPoint, Grey = NSBezierPath fill]

Grey bezier representation of string drawn using:

```
NSAffineTransform *moveFinal = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[moveFinal translateXBy:x yBy:y];
[textBezier transformUsingAffineTransform:moveFinal];
```

and the purple string via

```
[testString drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)
        withAttributes:attributes];
```

Same attributes, same input positions, different location in view.
And it just gets worse with rotated text.


**UPDATE #1**

Looks like it's boiling down to different bounding boxes returned by

- `NSString sizeWithAttributes:`
- `NSBezierPath bounds`

Now experimenting with `NSString` boundingRectWithSize

Comment: Bounds of the drawing are not the same as size of text. For example, a big roman italic *f* will draw far behind bounds of the box that is returned by `NSAttributedString size`.

Comment: Yep, that's why I've switched to `boundingRectWithSize`.   Good intro about various font dimensions can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontHandling/Tasks/GettingFontMetrics.html)   where sizeWithAttributes seems to use the outer bounding box and `NSBezierPath bounds` the actual area occupied by the glyphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW - Working now.

Using `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:` with the `NSStringDrawingUsesDeviceMetrics` option gives some good text dimensions to work with, including the actual bounding box occupied by the string when drawn and the offset of the first glyph.

Offset the `NSBezierPath` returned from bezierWithFont: by that amount and you're good to go..